# unable to updateMany inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array that I would like to save into a Group collections contact array.
My theory is to run a forEach loop over the array and " for each " element in the array run a command to push that element into the documents contact array.

When I run this nothing is happening. Im not seeing any errors, but it does NOT save in the database

Here is my function

```
// example of finished Matches array that I want to loop over and push each row into contacts array

const Matches = [
    "61380eeda0817b22c",
    "61380f14a0817b22c",
    "614c38608b931604b",
    "614c39598b931604b"
]
```

````
 const addContactsToGroup = async (req, res) => {
            const { groupId, selectedRows } = req.body

            const group = await Group.findById(groupId) //successfully got the groupId
               
            const Matches = selectedRows.filter(row => {
                    const isMatched = group.contacts.some(groupContacts => groupContacts === row)
                    return !isMatched
                })
                Matches.forEach(match => { // this is not working for some reason?
                    Group.updateMany({ '_id': groupId}, {$push: {contacts : match}})
                })
                res.status(201).json({message: "Successfully updated"})
        
            }```
````

Comment: should write `await` before `await Group.updateMany`, second this is a totally bad habit to execute the query in any loop, instead, you can use [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Comment: Instead of using forEach, consider using `$each` inside the push operator.